# Ruby on Rails: jquery Datepicker alternate field format change

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datepicker, format

I'm trying to search on a date, and the format in my database is, 2012-05-15. When I use datepicker, I have it so that the user can pick a date and it is then displayed as 15-05-2012.

I'm wanting to search on the 2012-05-15 format, without changing the way the viewer sees it. I tried to change format in the model, but had no luck.

Here's my search view:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
<%=  text_field_tag("start_date") %></br>
<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>

<% end %>
```

Here's my application.js:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#start_date').val("");
    jQuery('#start_date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
});
```

My Controller:

```
def search


@project_search = Project.search( params[:start_date].order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginated_for_index(per_page, page)

   @project = Project.new(params[:project])

respond_to do |format|
      format.html # search.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @project }
    end

end
```

and my model:

```
def self.search(search_start_date) 
  return scoped unless search_start_date.present?
  where([start_date LIKE ?, "%#{search_start_date}%"])
end
```

I tried using jquery options, but had no luck.

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('#start_date').val("");
jQuery('#start_date').datepicker({altField: '#start_date2', dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});


});
```

Hopefully someone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `dateFormat` in the jQuery Datepicker instance options **is** going to change the way your users see the date.

In your model

```
def self.search(search_start_date) 
  return scoped unless search_start_date.present?
  search_start_date = Date.parse(search_start_date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  where([start_date LIKE ?, "%#{search_start_date}%"])
end
```

Validating `search_start_date`'s initial format to ensure it's otherwise should be considered too.

Comment: I'm not sure how my answer caused you to try `Date.parse("%d-%m-%Y")`; `"%d-%m-%Y"` is definitely not a valid date. I updated my answer to be more explicit.

Comment: You did it! Thank you very much!